# Jquery tag selection

Tags: jquery

Probably pretty simple, but I seem to miss the trick the somewhere. Here is my question -

```
<div id=main-content> 
  <select id="syllabus"></select>
  <select id="subjects"></select>
<div>
```

How do I select the tags inside div tag using jquery?

To do something like -

```
   $("#main-content").[something].("#syllabus").append("<option>Maths</option>")
```

Thank You!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually it's:

```
$('#main-content #syllabus').append(...);
```

Comment: people... c'mon! the target element is an ID already. NO need to go-down-the-tree by ID. "ID.append(el)" is quite enough.

Comment: @verdure amico, if that works for you that does not mean it's the best answer. In the future try to accept answers that are technically correct and fast and not redundant. Not for you. For the people that will browse for an answer to a similar question. Thanks. Happy coding.

Comment: I was assuming he had multiple elements that had 'syllabus' as an id. Maybe I should have been been clearer about that?

Comment: rgin ... please tell me: do you really advice to use multiple ID on the same page?

Comment: No, but we don't always have that choice, do we? My answer was just a solution to what I thought he was having a problem with.

Comment: @rgin: Thing is, we *do* always have that choice.  We're teaching your future coworkers here.  I'd rather teach them right.  :)  If the question is like "how do i get this other element that has the same ID?", the only correct answer (and the one i'll give) is "Don't do that.  Your HTML is invalid, and there's no telling what a browser will do with it.  Make your IDs unique first, then we'll talk if that hasn't already solved your problem."  Anything else just allows the real problem to continue.

Answer (score 3):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/8tRHu/)

```
$('#syllabus').append("<option>Maths</option>");
```

You are already pointing to an ID element so there's definitely no reason to use other selectors than the el ID it self. `('#syllabus')`.

You can also use `.appendTo()` method:

```
$("<option>Maths</option>").appendTo('#syllabus');
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<div id="main-content">
```

instead of

```
<div id=main-content>
```

you can use

```
 $("#main-content").children("#syllabus").append("<option>Maths</option>")
```

UPDATE

i used a common senarion here , but you can use also

```
$('#select_id').append('<option>val</option>');
```

Comment: No need for the `("#main-content").children`.  Since the element has an ID, that's all you need to specify.

Comment: people... c'mon! the target element is an ID already. NO need to go-down-the-tree by ID. "ID.append(el)" is quite enough.

Comment: i tried to use a common senario , i thougt not only this problem . if you want only to this use $('#select_id').append('<option>val</option>');

Answer (score 0):

syllabus is already an id(unque in page).Then you can select in directly like

```
$("#syllabus")
```

if you still stick with it you can Select like this

```
$("#main-content > #syllabus")
```

Comment: people... c'mon! the target element is an ID already. NO need to go-down-the-tree by ID. "ID.append(el)" is quite enough.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
$("div#main-content select")
```

Comment: How would i specify the individual select tags ?

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#main-content select').each(function() {
  $(this).append('<option>Maths</option>');
});
```

That way you will add option tag for both selects. if you need different actions you can just select by id `$('#syllabus')`

Comment: becouse you have two selects and $('#main-content select') returns both.

Comment: @simon: ...you do realize you can `.append` to both of them at the same time?  `$('#main-content select').append('<option>Maths</option>');` would do the same things.  That's part of the coolness of jQuery.  But unless that's what's needed here, it's probably a bad idea.  I got the impression that the OP was looking for a way to address each select box individually.